# How to start and stop local server automatically?

Tags: angular, server, automation, localhost

I have a site on Angular, that needs to be run on local server. But at the same time, the server needs to be started with a shortcut (that I have implemented already), and stopped, when a browser is closed (so it doesn't take resources).
I don't really know how to stop a server automatically. Maybe I need some shell script running in the background and checking the state from time to time, or something like that.
Any ideas?

Comment: How would you do it manually? Then automate that with e.g. Autoit

Comment: @Xenobiologist unfortunately, I need to write a shell script for that :) In particular, I am building this project in Team City, so I need to pre-define all actions in code

Answer (score 1):

I would write a batch script to check if (e.g Chrome) is running. Check that after every 5 seconds and if found that chrome has been closed then also terminate `ng serve` serving cmd.

Following script will run `cmd1` which lets you `ng serve` by opening `cmd2`. `cmd1` itself will remain ticking on background checking every 5 sec if `chrome.exe` is running. If so, it loops again. If no `chrome.exe` has been found it will terminate window with title `ng serve` (a.k.a `cmd2`).

Change `set myApp-dir=C:\Users\<username>\IdeaProjects\myApp-frontend` to your dir what you want to serve and of course change the `<username>` to your username. Rest of the code can be left unchanged.

Save to desktop with notepad as something.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
:: Directory for the project
set myApp-dir=C:\Users\<username>\IdeaProjects\myApp-frontend
ECHO 1. myApp-frontend ng serve

echo.

:Start
CHOICE /C 1 /M "Choose:"
echo.

:: Note - list ERRORLEVELS in decreasing order

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO start-app

:start-app
start cmd.exe /k "chdir "%myApp-dir%" & ng serve"
 
@echo off
:loop
tasklist /FI "ImageName eq chrome.exe"  | find /i "chrome" > nul || goto :chrome_exited 
:: wait 5 seconds before checking again
timeout /t 5 >nul
echo checking if chrome has exited...
goto :loop

:chrome_exited
echo Chrome has exited! Killing "ng serve" cmd.
set toKill=ng serve
tasklist /V /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %toKill%" | find /I "%toKill%" >NUL && (taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %toKill%" /T /F)


GOTO Start

:End
pause
```

Comment: That looks like a decent solution, but it should be also compatible with other browsers too :)
Moreover, many developers in my company don't close browsers for ages, so I guess one needs to check opened tabs and see if any of them is running my site.

Comment: Yeah, I mean sure that would be nice. More browser support can be added, and I am pretty sure tabs can be distinguished. But more importantly, how would you know which tab is your application. By what params would you identify it?